# custom header view for submenu of contextmenu throws error

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to add a custom title header for submenues of a context menu?

i wrote this method to change the look of the title of the submenu (background green and the text color white)

```
public void setContextMenuHeader(SubMenu menu, String title, int iconId){
    if(menu == null){
        return;
    }
    View vgDialogTitle = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_title, null);
    ((TextView)vgDialogTitle.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_text)).setText(title);
    ((ImageView)vgDialogTitle.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_icon)).setImageResource(iconId);
    menu.clearHeader();
    menu.setHeaderView(vgDialogTitle);

}
```

R.layout.dialog_title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/dialog_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but when i call this method i get following errror:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child\'s parent first.

i can change the look of the header for the normal context-menu with the same layout file (with setHeaderView()), but not for the submenu

this is how i call the method to try to change the title for the submenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo = item.getMenuInfo();
    if (menuInfo != null) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        lastCheckedItemPosition = acmInfo.position;
    }
    final FavoriteItem favouriteItem = favouriteAdapter.getItem(lastCheckedItemPosition);
    setContextMenuHeader(item.getSubMenu(), favouriteItem.getName(), R.drawable.ic_tab_favorite);
```

EDIT: i was also not able to change the header backbground with the style.xml. if this wold work it would be the same good

Comment: I think your have to try menu.removeAllViews() insted of menu.clearHeader()...

Comment: but the interface SubMenu does not contain the method removeAllViews()